# onPress/onRelease in Android

Tags: android

Is there any kind of onPress and onRelease for android buttons like in flash?

Comment: If you implement `KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener`, then you will have access to `onPress()` and `onRelease()`

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky that's wrong and this is a 5 year old question...

Comment: Depending on how you look at it: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener.html#onRelease(int).  But not really for Buttons per se.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Instead of an onClickListener, you have to use an OnTouchListener. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Answer (score 22):

try this:

```
    someView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            if (arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                runEnemy(); 
            else
                stopEnemy();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

arg1.getAction()**==0** it's mean ACTION_DOWN http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN

Answer (score 15):

It is too late, but maybe someone will find it useful:

```
mButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    Log.d("Pressed", "Button pressed");
                else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)

                 Log.d("Released", "Button released");
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Handling UI Events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) on the android docs, you specifically want onTouch if you want to listen to down and release. If you are doing this just to change the look of a button there are other ways to handle this in button using [state lists](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

Answer (score 1):

You may change `mButton`, what is yours instead. And you may add paranthesis after `if` and `else if`

```
mButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                Log.d("Pressed", "Button pressed");
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)

             Log.d("Released", "Button released");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
```

And this code is from my side:

```
// butona basınca bir ses çekince bir ses geliyor.
    sescal.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            { 

                Log.d("Pressed", "Button pressed");
                mp.start();
            }
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {

                Log.d("Released", "Button released");
                mp2.start();
            }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
```