# Android: simplest approach to detect when user stops scrolling a custom scroll view?

Tags: android

I'm very new to Android development and I'm looking for a way to trigger a certain function x when the user has stopped scrolling.. Rather than personally implement a function to compare the value returned by `getScrollY()` (as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181828/android-detect-when-scrollview-stops-scrolling)) is there a simpler approach? (like the one provided in the Cocoa Framework for iOS development)

> (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate

*[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181828/android-detect-when-scrollview-stops-scrolling) was answered more than a year ago so I'm thinking if by any chance the present Android API may have, by now, provided developers with a simpler approach to doing it.*

Answer (score 0):

See this post:  [onPress/onRelease in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597513/onpress-onrelease-in-android).
Just look for ACTION_UP instead of ACTION_DOWN in the example.